# How to truncate column in order to create indexes?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have the following table in postgresql:

```
database=# \d dic
                Table "public.dic"
   Column    |          Type           | Modifiers
-------------+-------------------------+-----------
 id          | bigint                  |
 stringvalue | character varying(2712) |

database=# create index idStringvalue on dic(id,stringvalue);
ERROR:  index row size 2728 exceeds maximum 2712 for index "idstringvalue"
HINT:  Values larger than 1/3 of a buffer page cannot be indexed.
Consider a function index of an MD5 hash of the value, or use full text indexing.
```

I dont know why is the error is coming when the size of stringvalue is 2712.

I want to truncate all the stringvalue's in dic which cause the above error. However, I am not getting how to do so. Can someone please help me with this?

I am am even fine with deleting the rows which cause this error. Is there some way by which I may do so?

Comment: [This related answer on dba.SE](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25138/index-max-row-size-error/25140#25140) may help, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your column probably contains multibyte data: whereas the varchar(2712) deals with that just fine, it kind of makes sense that the indexing algorithm would be computing the c-string length, since memory considerations is what the latter is worrying about.

Theoretically, you can't go wrong by dividing the limit by four, i.e. use an unbounded varchar for the column, and index the first 600 characters or so, e.g.:

```
create index on dic((left(stringvalue, 600)));
```

This does raise the question of whether you actually need to index anything this large, though, since the value of doing so primarily lies in sorting. Postgres (correctly) suggests that you use an md5 of the value (if you're only interested in strict equality) or full text search (if you're interested in fuzzy matching).